# Under what conditions can SocketChannel.hashCode() change?

Tags: java, nio, hashcode

`SocketChannel.hashCode()` returns an `int` value based on the hash of a `SocketChannel` Object. I presume that elements of this object can change at different points which can't be controlled, so my question is how constant is the `hashCode` of this Object?

Comment: What actual type are you using? ``SocketChannel`` is an abstract class.

Answer (score 4):

`SocketChannel` does not override `hashCode()` (checked with OpenJDK 1.8.0_31). In other words, the default implementation of `Object`'s `hashCode()` is used, which should not change for the duration of the object's lifecycle.

Comment: But *unlikely* to be constant across multiple runs of the application.

Comment: @IanMcLaird "Unlinkely" is an understatement :-)